# How to use PHP regex to replace a space AND comma AND combination of space AND comma with arbitrary string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do you use PHP's preg_match to replace:

1. White space, and
2. Comma, and
3. Combination of white space AND comma

For example, consider the following string:

```
apple orange,strawberry, coconut
```

Note that:

1. Only white space is used between "apple" and "orange"
2. Only comma is used between "orange" and "strawberry"
3. Both white space and comma is used between "strawberry" and "coconut"

How do I use preg_match to replace all occurences of the listed elements above with the word YES, that results in the following string

```
appleYESorangeYESstrawberryYEScoconut
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://rubular.com, http://refiddle.com

Comment: What about combination of multiple white spaces and commas, like in "coconut,, kiwi,, ,, ,, ,,,,apple"? Do you care about not matching that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[\s,]+/', 'YES', $str);
```

Comment: Yeah, it will also match "coconut,, kiwi,,  ,, ,, ,,,,apple". Which is not in the OP's problem description :) I'm not sure whether he cares about this case, though

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\s+|\s*,\s*/', 'YES', $str);
```